# Convert special characters in string to Unicode Hex Code?

Tags: c#, string

For example, I have the string "Möller". I want to transform it to "`M&#xF6;ller`" according to the Hex Code in this link: http://www.codetable.net/hex/f6

I want to detect all special characters (not the normal alphanumeric) and automatically convert them.

So far the only examples I have seen are just to normal Hex. Is there a way to get the Unicode Hex Code?

Thanks

Comment: `string encoded = WebUtility.HtmlEncode("Möller");` - gives you encoded string. But is used decimal, not hexadecimal characters.

Comment: The format you are after looks like XML or HTML. If so, why not let an appropriate writer do what it needs to do, given the document encoding you specify? Do you need something that it wouldn't? What's wrong with "ö", anyway? It's perfectly readable, as are many other letters, symbols, ….—Is this an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/xy-problem/info)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to match any Unicode letter but an ASCII letter. It is easy to achieve with a regex:

```
[\p{L}-[A-Za-z]]
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5B%5Cp%7BL%7D-%5BA-Za-z%5D%5D&i=M%C3%B6ller%20D%C4%85b)

In C# code, use `Regex.Replace` with the match evaluator to convert these letters into hex codes.

```
var s = "Möller";
s  = Regex.Replace(s, @"[\p{L}-[a-zA-Z]]", m => 
    string.Join(string.Empty, m.Value.Select(c=>string.Format("&#x{0:X};", Convert.ToInt32(c))).ToArray()));
Console.WriteLine(s); // => M&#xF6;ller
```

See the [C# demo](http://ideone.com/JgJ1AP)