# convert special char ‘ to hex value in C#

Tags: c#, hex

i know how to convert char to hex. but when it comes to special char normal conversion method is not working.

hex value for ‘ is 91
Ref : http://www.aboutmyip.com/AboutMyXApp/AsciiChart.jsp

my code

```
            string text =  "‘";
            char[] chars = text.ToCharArray();
            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            foreach (char c in chars)
            {
                stringBuilder.Append(((Int16)c).ToString("x"));
            }
            String textAsHex = stringBuilder.ToString();
```

am getting output as 2018 but what should i get is 91

Comment: Check if this helps - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40967540/convert-special-characters-in-string-to-unicode-hex-code

Comment: That isn't an apostrophe (U+0091), it is a left single quote at code point U+2018 (aka "opening curly quote").

Comment: Just thought: are you thinking of the Windows code page rather than Unicode? All .NET strings are Unicode, when you load using `Encoding.ASCII` the "extended ASCII" characters over 0x7f will be converted to their Unicode equivalents.

Comment: ASCII is a 7-bit encoding. What values above 0x7F represent in a byte-sized character depends on the code page.

Comment: For example if you look at [this chart (CP-1252)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252) it has that character as 91 and its unicode codepoint as 2018

Comment: Specifically: the character at position 0x91 of [Windows-1250 code page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252) is represented in [Uncode differently](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotation_mark#Unicode_code_point_table),.

Comment: I think something else is happening.  There is no way that you can get 2018 from 91.  It test the following code and it works :             char test = (char)0x91;
            int results = (Int16)test;

Comment: thx u for all your feedback's let check and comeback

Answer (score 0):

based on [@Richard,@harold,@jdweng & @500-Internal server error] feedback i found the solution to my problem.this will include **extended ASCII table**
[convert character to hex value]

find the working code beolow

```
        private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string str = "‘";
            var encoding = System.Text.Encoding.Default;
            var values = encoding.GetBytes(str);
            Decimal dec = values[0];
            var hex = ToHexString(dec);
            string result = hex.ToString();
        }

       public static string ToHexString(Decimal dec)
        {
            var sb = new StringBuilder();
            while (dec > 1)
            {
                var r = dec % 16;
                dec /= 16;
                sb.Insert(0, ((int)r).ToString("X"));
            }
            return sb.ToString();
        }
```

Output is 91

Comment: Which "Extended ASCII" table? `Encoding.Default` is a specific one but it varies across systems, users and time. It could be exactly what you want, if that is stable enough. But, in most cases, you want a specific, fixed charcter encoding that everyone knows.